# Is a memcpy between differently aligned pointers UB?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, memcpy, c11

As far as I understand, the following piece of code exhibits undefined behaviour in C11:

```
#include <string.h>

struct aaaa { char bbbb; int cccc; };

int main(void) {
    unsigned char buffer[sizeof(struct aaaa)] = { 0 };
    struct aaaa *pointer = &buffer[0];

    return (*pointer).cccc;
}
```

According to [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) section 6.5.3.2 clause 4,

> If an invalid value has been assigned to the pointer, the behavior of the unary `*` operator is undefined.

which is accompanied by a footnote that clarifies that

> Among the invalid values for dereferencing a pointer by the unary `*` operator are a null pointer, an address inappropriately aligned for the type of object pointed to, and the address of an object after the end of its lifetime.

It's unlikely that `struct aaaa *` and `unsigned char *` have the same alignment, so we assigned an invalid value to `pointer`, and using `*pointer` therefore causes UB.

However, can I copy the structure?

```
#include <string.h>

struct aaaa { char bbbb; int cccc; };

int main(void) {
    unsigned char buffer[sizeof(struct aaaa)] = { 0 };
    struct aaaa target;

    memcpy(&target, buffer, sizeof(struct aaaa));

    return target.cccc;
}
```

Here, we pass a `struct aaaa *` and `unsigned char *` to `memcpy`. While that seems just as bad as the first piece of code, I can't find any wording in C11 that rules that this code exhibits UB. **Does this usage of `memcpy` cause undefined behaviour?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, `memcpy` doesn't make any assumptions about alignement. It is functionally equivalent to copying byte by byte.

BTW, accessing an `auto` object through an lvalue of a different type that is not a character type leads to undefined behavior, regardless of alignment. This is a violation of the *effective type rule*, C11 6.5 p6 and p7.

Comment: But what does it mean to "copy byte by byte" in C11? Maybe the first byte will be fine, but how will you copy `buffer[1]` to `*(((unsigned char *)&target)+1)`? Surely, the latter expression has UB...

Comment: @Rhymoid, it is the same as casting the addresses to `char*` and `char const*`, respectively, and then doing a `for` loop for copying. Accessing individual bytes through character pointers is always allowed.

Comment: While `memcpy` itself does not generally make assumptions about alignment, it may exploit assumptions a compiler makes *elsewhere* about alignment.  For example,if a compiler sees that the arguments to `memcpy` are of type `uint32_t`, it may generate `memcpy` code that will fail if the pointers aren't aligned for that type.  Whether or not the compiler would normally care about the alignment of a pointer which is converted to `uint32_t*` and back to `void*` without being dereferenced as a `uint32_t`, conversion of a pointer to `uint32_t*` will invoke Undefined Behavior if it is not aligned...

Comment: ...for that type (even if it is never dereferenced as that type).  Since the only way `memcpy` would receive unaligned pointers would be if UB had already occurred, there would be no need for the compiler to handle that case.

Answer (score -1):

From what I understand, both cases are UB (but not because of the call to `memcpy`), because the compiler does not enforce alignment of start offsets of variables properly. You can enforce alignment with compiler-specific attributes to be sure, but this is of course a platform-specific solution.

Assuming the start offsets are aligned (this is an assumption from practice), like compilers usually do it to gain perfomance:

In your first example you assign at first buffer index 0. `buffer` is usually aligned correctly. `cccc` will be aligned, too, because the `struct` is not packed. It should not cause a problem in this case.

In second example when using `memcpy` everything will copy properly, because (internally) it tries its best to do aligned copy for performance and when it is not possible, it copies byte-wise. And here again, all structures and buffers are aligned with the restrictions I mentioned above.

What is the actual problem here?

You would risk it (visibly in practice) if you assign `&buffer[1]` (given, it is usually not aligned). An access to `cccc` will load a word from unaligned address. On some architectures it causes the dreaded SIGBUS. x86 detects unaligned addressing and slows down a bit (perhaps), but does not crash.

Comment: There is no basis for assuming that `buffer` is properly aligned for type `struct aaaa`.

Comment: Yes, this is usually enforced by compiler-specific align attributes, I forgot. It's still true that there are no problems, when `buffer[0]` is aligned.

Comment: Your answer still assumes that `buffer` is aligned.